# Create SQL query with given Conditions

Tags: sql, performance, optimization

I have an SQL query of the form

```
SELECT 
    SUM(some_col) 
FROM
    (some table name here)
WHERE 
    some_common_condition AND
    some_condition1 AND 
    some_condition2 AND
    column_A = 'X'
GROUP BY 
    column_A;
```

`column_A` has some values for which I currently run this query for. Now for each of the unique values of `column_A` there are some associated conditions.

For eg, if `column_A` has 3 unique values `X,Y,Z`, all three have `some_common_condition` and some  specific conditions associated with it,i.e,

- for `X` -> `some_condition1 AND some_condition2`
- for `Y` -> `some_condition3 AND some_condition4`
- for `Z` -> `some_condition5 AND some_condition6`

I want to club all these conditions and make 1 single SQL query,which gives me corresponding `SUM(some_col)` for all the values of `column_A` (i.e. `X,Y,Z`).

Now one obvious way is

```
SELECT *
  FROM(SELECT SUM(some_col) AS val_X FROM (table) WHERE conditions_for_X UNION ALL
       SELECT SUM(some_col) AS val_Y FROM (table) WHERE conditions_for_X UNION ALL
       SELECT SUM(some_col) AS val_Z FROM (table) WHERE conditions_for_X -- UNION ALL a.s.o.
      )
```

I want to know a solution which only hits the database once. Above query uses 3 select statements, hitting the DB three times, which is bad for scalability reasons.

Comment: What about using `OR`: `(columnA = 'X' AND <conditions...>) OR (columnA = 'Y' AND <conditions...>) OR...`?

Comment: The number of times such a query "hits the database" is *entirely* up to your SQL optimizer, which is determined by your specific DBMS, and other facotrs.  It may be three times, it may be more, it may be less.  It cannot be readily generalized as you are assuming.

Answer (score 2):

Does this answer your question?

```
SELECT SUM(some_col) FROM ...

WHERE 
  (column_A = 'X' AND some_condition1 AND some_condition2) OR
  (column_A = 'Y' AND some_condition3 AND some_condition4) OR
  (column_A = 'Z' AND some_condition5 AND some_condition6)

GROUP BY column_A;
```